# LXC4 no network (Fc34)

Tags: lxc

I tried to use LXC4 under Fc34, but in containers no network: "Network is unreachable."
(lxc-4.0.6-2.fc34.x86_64)

```
# fc34 container config:
# ...
# Distribution configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/common.conf
lxc.arch = x86_64

# Container specific configuration
lxc.rootfs.path = dir:/var/lib/lxc/fedora34/rootfs
lxc.uts.name = fedora34

# Network configuration
lxc.net.0.type = veth
lxc.net.0.link = lxcbr0
lxc.net.0.flags = up
lxc.net.0.hwaddr = ......

# not working, it has IP, but no network:
#lxc.net.0.ipv4.address = 10.0.3.100/24
#lxc.net.0.ipv4.gateway = 10.0.3.1
```

Manualy in container:

## ip addr add 10.0.3.100/24 dev eth0

## ip route add default via 10.0.3.1 dev eth0

## ip route

default via 10.0.3.1 dev eth0

10.0.3.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.100

## ping 8.8.8.8

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=17.3 ms

## vi /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

DNS=8.8.8.8

## restart container: cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8
search .

## ping ns.google.com

ping: ns.google.com: The name or service is unknown

What do I need to config for auto settings?

Answer (score 0):

It works.
The firewalld had no masquerade rule:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=FedoraWorkstation --add-masquerade --permanent
```